# @font-face doesnt work when opening link in new tab by middle-button click

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have strange problem, I have image thumbs on my index.html file and while I click them with left mouse button another html (placed in sub directory to the root one) opens containing bigger image - this way everything works fine, looks fine and so on.

But when I click the thumbnail with middle mouse button, opening it in the new tab, suddenly font-face doesnt work and it uses some default serif font (arial possibly). All other css settings are applied just fine (font size, spacing, all div/class settings), just font-face seems to get ignored.

Structure of directories is as follows (example):

Root:

```
index.html
/big/big.html
/css/main.css
/css/fontfiles.otf
```

When I click thumb, file big.html opens which has `../css/main.css` while index obviously has just `/css/main.css`.

Previously I had all the big.html files placed in root directory but it was kinda messy so I put them in subdir /big/ and as I said it works fine when I left click the thumbnails, but font-face doesnt work when middle button clicking and opening it in new tab.

Font-face code (files are placed in root/css/) :

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myriad';
  src: url('../css/MyriadPro-LightSemiCn.otf?') format('otf'), url('../css/MyriadPro-  LightSemiCn.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myriad-bold';
  src: url('../css/MyriadPro-SemiCn.otf?') format('otf'), url('../css/MyriadPro-  SemiCn.woff') format('woff');
}
```

(I already tried with just `/fontname.otf`)

Any ideas?

TLDR; all the html/css stuff works but when I open sub-page by middle-button clicking font-face gets ignored and displays default font, when left-click it works just fine

Comment: Could you provide the `@font-face` code form your css file please ?

Comment: Added, little bit convoluted but thats the only way I managed to make it work in all the browsers

Comment: How are you applying the font-face to the element you want to use? Are you using font-family? Is it in an external stylesheet?
This sounds a lot like a loading time problem to me, but if it's not being applied via JS I can't see how it would be...

Comment: Yes I use standard font-family via external css file. I checked it and problem occurs only in Firefox and only with opening thumbnail link in the new tab, on left click font loads just fine.